# how to stop animation Javascript?

Tags: javascript

When hovering over the menu, I want to trigger the animation.
I want to stop it if the menu is no longer overflown.

**CORRECTION**

```
     animeMiddle() {
            this.menu.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                  this.ctx = this.middle.animate([
                            {width: '0'},
                            {width: '100%'}
                        ],
                        {
                            duration: 1000, iterations: Infinity
                        })

            });
            this.menu.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                this.ctx.cancel();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Animation.pause()` is what you need.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/pause)

From MDN:

> The pause() method of the Web Animations API's Animation interface
>   suspends playback of the animation.

Comment: doesn't work, pause() is not a function when I tried : this.middle.pause()

Comment: @Laura you're using an arrow function, so `this` might be a different object. Are you sure you're calling the method on the correct object?
Also, the two calls are in different methods. `this` is different in different contexts.